# Windows Directory Change Event

Tags: c#, events, directory, windows-explorer

Is there a way you can catch the event from windows when the explorer tries to change/switch the directory it's looking at. And if so, is there a way to do something before it changes, and then cancel the change if necessary?

I understand how to use `FileSystemWatcher`, and **this is not what I want** to use

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this? What are you hoping to solve? Are you writing a shell extension, or are you hoping that this will work inside of your regular C# application? Why should you be able to control what the user does with Windows Explorer? What happens if they use the command line or some other utility to browse directories?

Comment: I'm writing a folder locking program, and basically I need to know when the user tries to change directories, and catch the event, prompt for a password, and cancel the change if the get it wrong.

Comment: That isn't going to work very well for numerous reasons, some of which I alluded to in my last comment. Windows provides all sorts of built-in security features to handle things like this. Why don't you use them instead of trying to write your own?

Comment: Why not just use file system security?  NTFS has the ability to assign permissions to files and directories.

Comment: I want to write my own one, for academic purposes,  two for fun, and three for some security program that is integrated into windows and very lightweight and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).
Here is a [sample](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137).

Comment: I want to see if the directory isn't changed, but rather clicked on... Like, if the user clicks into a directory

Answer (score 0):

To break the trend of poorly informed answerers... this question has nothing to do with watching file system changes.

The only chance you have at doing this is to watch all of your user's actions on all explorer Windows. Even then there are ways to get around it (as Cody eluded to). There are ways to implement custom security policies in Windows, however this is not one of them.

Comment: That seems fair I suppose. Just a little side project I wanted to do for fun while I'm in school. Merely an academic project =)

Comment: @Buggie: This is not a good academic project. Pick another one. :-) Seriously, this kind of stuff really needs to be handled by the operating system. It's not intended to be done by an application, and any app that tries to do it will not do it right. Not to mention it'll be pretty difficult and take some advanced skills to even get a sort-of-working demo. If you're not rather experienced with Windows programming, you're going to get frustrated and be spending a lot of time posting "why doesn't this work?" questions on SO. You don't want to give me that many chances to leave snarky comments.

Comment: @CodyGray - I won't debate any part of your comment to Buggie. I just question your comment that this is better left to the OS. Isn't that the reason PAM was invented (and semi-supported by Windows)?

Comment: Hmm, I thought [PAM](http://www.pamcookingspray.com/) was invented so that my waffles don't stick to the iron. I suppose you mean "pluggable authentication modules", and then I'd have to say I have no idea. I'm a Windows programmer, and it's really not supported there at all. I suppose that yes, theoretically, there could be some extensibility architecture provided by the OS for this purpose, but I'd still consider that "handled by the OS". NT's security system is pretty complex and seems perfectly suitable for this purpose. Either way, you don't do it by interacting with Explorer.

Comment: @CodyGray - lol and agreed. My point was more toward the original poster (even though I aimed it at you). In a roundabout way it could be considered a way to answer his question without answering it.